# Why Webench power tool suggested using this Hot-Swap Controller (TPS2420) for my design?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter

I was trying to build dc to dc converter that has one input which is anywhere between 9V-20V and has 4 outputs: 5v @ 2.5A, 3.3V @ 2.5A, 3.3 @ 1.5A, and 1.5V @ 1.5A. So, I sequenced the outputs and checked the Hot-Swap box and clicked next, then I noticed that my generated circuit has the TPS2420 as a Hot-Swap Controller which can have 4A as a maximum output current while the total of needed currents through the 4 outputs should be around 8A !!!!

Kindly, what is the thing that I'm misunderstanding here?!

[Image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3mrp.jpg)

[Image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll9Qg.jpg)

[Image-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4fA2.jpg)

Comment: Maybe the suggestion is that you use **four** of these devices.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, good point! But how come the power architect tool didnt show me four of them when generated the circuit!!!

Comment: In my experience with WeBench, repeated components (such as capacitors) will have a x4 (or xN) instead of showing multiple of them in the schematic. As always, posting a pic of whatever you are referring to would help a lot.

Comment: @Wesley Lee, I appreciate your feedback, images were added!

Comment: @Wesley Lee, Would you please elaborate on this phrase: " repeated components (such as capacitors) will have a x4 (or xN) instead of showing multiple of them in the schematic."

Comment: Because you hadn't posted images before I wasnt sure what part of webench you were using. On parts where they present a schematic with components, instead of showing 4 symbols of the same capacitor, they will show one symbol with a x4 by its value (22uF 10V x4 for example).

Comment: @Wesley Lee, I see.